# Laravel 5.6 custom storage link/mount to other location on Windows OS

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.6 custom storage link/mount to other location on Windows OS

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration

`php artisan storage:link` will point the

`http://localhost/storage` to `c:/project/storage/app/public`

means visit `http://localhost/storage/image.jpg` = `c:/project/storage/app/public/image.jpg`

but how to custom the uri link to other location ? eg..

http://localhost/`ramdisk`/image.jpg link to `z:/ramdisk/image.jpg`

or

http://localhost/`avatar`/image.jpg link to `z:/avatar/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: why would you like to do that? The images you upload should be in `/storage/app/...` or in `/public/images/...` Other disks may be unavailable if putting the app on a server.

To clarify, the `php artisan storage:link` only creates a symlink in `/public/` folder pointing to the `app/public`. (I think in 5.6 it has absolute path so on server or after moving the application you have to delete and generate it again.)

So if you really want to access disk `z` on your PC from the app you should create a symlink in `/public/` folder with the desired name. For example:
`http://localhost/ramdisk/...` would be a symlink named `ramdisk` in the `public` folder and would point to `z:/ramdisk/`. Then you would be able to access the folder contents as you wish.

Of course you can have multiple symlinks so you would create another one for the `avatar` folder too. Also make sure that disk `z` has a public access.

I was not able to test it, but I am sure that it would work, however I would not recommend it. If you want to use something in your app it should be within the app. (Except S3 drivers like amazon cloud storage.) I hope it helped.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, actually the app only designed and work on local only, because i have alot data is from other programs on Windows, it is not easy to put all inside the project, so any command i can make the symlink point the /public/ramdisk to z:/ramdisk ?

Comment: This link should help you: [Symbolic Links](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/). I am not sure but maybe in windows shortcuts would do too, and the can be created from the context menu, but I not really using Windows

Comment: thankyou for the link, solved my problem, `This trick can be used for all sorts of things, including syncing any folder with programs like Dropbox, Google Drive, and OneDrive.`